# Messages.app asks for iChat every time I open it

Tags: messages, ichat

Every time I open up Messages, it asks me to locate iChat. This is on a new machine that I migrated from an old one on Lion and then upgraded to Mt. Lion. I don't have iChat on this machine any more, as far as I can tell. How do I stop it from prompting me? (It seems to happen only after a restart.)

[image]

Comment: Have you deleted that account from preferences if you don't want that account in use anymore? If that's too drastic, you should be able to deselect the "use this account" toggle to disable it.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the “locate iChat” dialog ?

Comment: @bmike: what account? I'm using the same accounts I was using under Lion: work gmail, personal gmail, imessage, bonjour, aim.

Comment: @duci9y: screenshot added.

Comment: Unless you are running a beta version of Messages, I presumed you had named an account iChat - perhaps I'm on the wrong path...

Comment: @bmike: I'm using the version of Messages.app that came with Mt. Lion

Comment: Bizarre - we'll have to wait for someone that has seen it or you to figure out why it's calling to locate another app.

Answer (score 1):

(I haven't upgraded to Mountain Lion myself, but my understanding is that Messages has subsumed iChat.) That looks like the AppleScript find-the-application-named-in-the-script dialog. Do you perhaps have something that somehow runs a script when you launch Messages? If so, find that script and edit it to refer to `application "Messages"` instead of `application "iChat"` if that works, or remove it entirely.